# "Leveling up" dans un jeu en français

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques, jeux, jargon

If I'm playing an online game such as World of Warcraft, how would I say the idiomatic expression "level up" in French?  I know I see "monter niveau" and such, but how would it be said colloquially?  For instance, how would I say,"I just leveled up to level 100."?

Comment: French players often use English or Frenglish, especially in MMO: je vais farm un peu pour avoir de l'XP (I'm gonna farm a bit to get some XP), je suis en train d'XP (I'm XP-ing, "XP" used as a verb, yes), j'ai up 100 (I just reached lvl 100, with "100" in French), etc. Sometimes the English verbs are conjugated like French verbs: to farm -> farmer, we are farming -> nous farmons, etc. All of this is, of course, totally unofficial and incorrect.

Comment: I'll add that the games themselves, when they have a French translation, don't use the English terms and have a real translation.

Comment: And I realize I wrote "often use" when I should have write "almost always use". "Our tank left us to go farming some mobs, so until he comes back I'll craft a new skill" could be said: "Notre **tank** a **leave** pour aller **farmer** des **mobs**, donc en attendant qu'il **back** je vais **crafter** un nouveau **skill**". I'm not exagerating, even if some of the words in this example would be more often said in French than in English/Frenglish. Note that we would almost always use "leave" even when it's "left" in English.

Answer (score 2):

I will say: "Je viens de passer au niveau 100"! "I just reached level 100"

For a game we will more use the verb "passer" in the sense of "to go, to pass, to reach" than "monter" which means  "going up"!

Answer (score 0):

Adding to what Loky said (**passer** niveau 100)... To be fair, most MMORPG player don't use the purest french to express themself when they speak about their game, and some of them are young. Also as you'd expect the french academy does not bother with video game.

> J'ai up [level/niveau] 100
>
> J'ai ding [level/niveau] 100

Note 100 is not "one hundred", it's "cent" in french. "Ding" is the onomatopoeia for leveling up in World of Warcraft used as a verb. You would sound like a childish young player, don't use it yourself.

**Monter [en] niveau** is totally acceptable and this is what should be used imho.

Comment: "Most MMORPG players don't use the **purest** French". I love the understatement! I do not think the French Academy is not interested, they just had a heart attack in the first 10 minutes seeing how butchered French is. :-)

Comment: @SteffX : "lfm mage capé intel (ilvl mini 35) pr rush le champ lexical des mmo en français, on est coincé sur 'level up' et notre tank a leave pr aller répa quand on a voulu proposer "ding". /w Orsenna plz"

Comment: @Steffx What is it you call *the purest french* ? Who is using that ? For which benefit ? How would you *butcher* a language ?

Comment: @RomainVALERI I was quoting the answer. Of course a true *purest French* would not make sense but the language used in MMO chats is nowhere near actual French, like "j'ai up level 44".

Comment: I have never heard anything about "ding" even though I'm a french gamer

Comment: "Ding" as a verb is often used but not **that** often. "J'ai ding 50 hier" = "I reached level 50 yesterday". Note that most of the time, we don't conjugate those unofficial verbs, but sometimes we do: "J'ai dingué 50 hier", "J'ai droppé une belle épée", "J'ai farmé des mobs". Sometimes we even conjugate same the English way, but it's pretty rare: "J'ai dinged 50 hier", "J'ai dropped une super épée", "J'ai farmed des mobs".

Comment: @SteffX You're totally right, I was adressing to Pierre, just a mistype.

Comment: @RomainVALERI I don't understand your questions. What I wanted to say with "not the purest french" is that when you say something like "J'ai up level 50" it's not academic french. But examples from Simon Déchamps's comment do exists.